# Incorrect SQL syntax pointing at empty bottom row

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have a set of data that I upload to SQL and since a couple of new columns have been added (abandoned IVR & answered IVR) it is failing to upload properly.

The data will now only land in the temp table and not the full data one, but what makes it all the more confusing is that it's saying their is a syntax error of ',' on the bottom line which is blank

This is my merge statement which is when I debug is saying where the potential error is. But I don't understand why the error is pointing at a blank row and stopping the upload from happening?

Could anyone give me any pointers, apologies for the code layout - I don't know how to set it out.

Thanks
Dan

```
sSQL = "MERGE [C3 ODS].Telephony AS Target USING (SELECT CallDate,VDN,VDN_Name,Skill,Skill_Name,Telephony_Lookup,Site,Team,SubTeam,Client, '" & _
    " Scheme,Calls_Offered,Calls_Answered,Calls_Abandoned,Calls_Abandoned_SLA,Calls_Answered_SLA,Average_TalkTime,Average_ACW,Average_HandleTime,  '" & _
    " Average_AbandonTime,Average_SpeedAnswer,TelephonySystem,TimePeriod1,TimePeriod2,TimePeriod3,TimePeriod4,TimePeriod5,TimePeriod6,TimePeriod7, '" & _
    " TimePeriod8,TimePeriod9,Abandon1,Abandon2,Abandon3,Abandon4,Abandon5,Abandon6,Abandon7,Abandon8,Abandon9,Abandon10,Answered1,Answered2, '" & _
    " Answered3,Answered4,Answered5,Answered6,Answered7,Answered8,Answered9,Answered10,DataLoad_Date,ClientGroup,LOB,ServiceLevel,Section, '" & _
    " ForecastGroup,AbandonedIVR,AnsweredIVR FROM [C3 ODS].Telephony_Temp) AS Temp " & _
    " ON Target.CallDate = Temp.CallDate AND Target.Telephony_Lookup = Temp.Telephony_Lookup WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET Target.Calls_Offered = Temp.Calls_Offered, '" & _
    " Target.Calls_Answered = Temp.Calls_Answered, Target.Calls_Abandoned = Temp.Calls_Abandoned, Target.Calls_Abandoned_SLA = Temp.Calls_Abandoned_SLA, '" & _
    " Target.Calls_Answered_SLA = Temp.Calls_Answered_SLA, Target.Average_TalkTime = Temp.Average_TalkTime, Target.Average_ACW = Temp.Average_ACW, '" & _
    " Target.Average_HandleTime = Temp.Average_HandleTime, Target.Average_AbandonTime = Temp.Average_AbandonTime, Target.Average_SpeedAnswer = Temp.Average_SpeedAnswer, '" & _
    " Target.VDN_Name = Temp.VDN_Name, Target.Skill_Name = Temp.Skill_Name, Target.Site = Temp.Site, Target.Team = Temp.Team, Target.SubTeam = Temp.SubTeam, '" & _
    " Target.ClientGroup = Temp.ClientGroup, Target.Client = Temp.Client,  Target.Scheme = Temp.Scheme " & _
    " WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (CallDate,VDN,VDN_Name,Skill,Skill_Name,Telephony_Lookup,Site,Team,SubTeam,Client,Scheme,Calls_Offered,Calls_Answered, '" & _
    " Calls_Abandoned,Calls_Abandoned_SLA,Calls_Answered_SLA,Average_TalkTime,Average_ACW,Average_HandleTime,Average_AbandonTime,Average_SpeedAnswer, '" & _
    " TelephonySystem,TimePeriod1,TimePeriod2,TimePeriod3,TimePeriod4,TimePeriod5,TimePeriod6,TimePeriod7,TimePeriod8,TimePeriod9,Abandon1,Abandon2, '" & _
    " Abandon3,Abandon4,Abandon5,Abandon6,Abandon7,Abandon8,Abandon9,Abandon10,Answered1,Answered2,Answered3,Answered4,Answered5,Answered6,Answered7, '" & _
    " Answered8,Answered9,Answered10,DataLoad_Date,ClientGroup,LOB,ServiceLevel,Section,ForecastGroup,AbandonedIVR,AnsweredIVR) " & _
    " VALUES (Temp.CallDate, Temp.VDN, Temp.VDN_Name, Temp.Skill, Temp.Skill_Name, Temp.Telephony_Lookup, Temp.Site, Temp.Team, Temp.SubTeam, '" & _
    " Temp.Client, Temp.Scheme, Temp.Calls_Offered, Temp.Calls_Answered, Temp.Calls_Abandoned, Temp.Calls_Abandoned_SLA, Temp.Calls_Answered_SLA, '" & _
    " Temp.Average_TalkTime, Temp.Average_ACW, Temp.Average_HandleTime, Temp.Average_AbandonTime, Temp.Average_SpeedAnswer, Temp.TelephonySystem, '" & _
    " Temp.TimePeriod1, Temp.TimePeriod2, Temp.TimePeriod3, Temp.TimePeriod4, Temp.TimePeriod5, Temp.TimePeriod6, Temp.TimePeriod7, Temp.TimePeriod8, '" & _
    " Temp.TimePeriod9, Temp.Abandon1, Temp.Abandon2, Temp.Abandon3, Temp.Abandon4, Temp.Abandon5, Temp.Abandon6, Temp.Abandon7, Temp.Abandon8, '" & _
    " Temp.Abandon9, Temp.Abandon10, Temp.Answered1, Temp.Answered2, Temp.Answered3, Temp.Answered4, Temp.Answered5, Temp.Answered6, Temp.Answered7, '" & _
    " Temp.Answered8, Temp.Answered9, Temp.Answered10, Temp.DataLoad_Date, Temp.ClientGroup, Temp.LOB, Temp.ServiceLevel, Temp.Section, '" & _
    " Temp.ForecastGroup, Temp.AbandonedIVR, Temp.AnsweredIVR);"
    Cn.Execute sSQL
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal sample, this query is huge.

Comment: is this MySQL or SQL Server ? you cannot set both tags please choose one

Comment: Sorry it's SQL Server

Comment: I don't know what would be a useful sample in this instance as there are so many columns in the VBA Code

Comment: Why do all the lines end with `'"` when they begin only with `"` ? That will completely mess up the SQL.

Comment: I didn't write the initial code unfortunately I've been left with the mess

Comment: This will probably take some time, but I'd format this code to look like SQL indentation, by properly separating the statements in their own lines and so forth. This will make it a lot easier for you (and for anyone else) to read it and spot the error. You might even find the error by yourself during the process.

Comment: Ok i've found the issue with the code but it is now not identifying the two new columns, 'Abandon IVR and Answered IVR' when loading the data 

Even though these two are in my data table - what would be the reason for this?

Comment: SOLVED - Someone has been very sloppy in their table creation and called one column Abandoned IVR instead of Abandon